# JDK 8u05 Windows 7 installation issue

Tags: java

this is my first topic . I've done a quick search to make sure im not posting an unessecary topic already existing. Im using Windows 7 32bit system and when im trying to install JDK 8u05. I downloaded the .exe file ( curious why there is no .rar archive available for download ) from the Oracle main website and when i try to run it , nothing happens. Just loads for a few seconds and then nothing. I tried restarting , re-downloading , turning off UAC , running as an admininstrator. Any suggestions ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: *this is my first **off** topic*

Comment: The .exe is an installer, and it should install the JDK on your system.  If it doesn't run at all, there is something wrong with your system.

Comment: something more specific ?

Answer (score 1):

Just solved this , i need to switch users . Seems there was no right in user i worked on. Thanks anyway !

Answer (score 0):

**Downloading the Installer**

If you save the self-installing executable file to disk without running it from the download page at the web site, note the file size specified on the download page. After the download has completed, verify that you have downloaded the complete file.

**Running the JDK Installer**

You must have administrative permissions in order to install the JDK on Microsoft Windows.

The file jdk-8version-windows-i586-i.exe is the JDK installer for 32-bit systems. The file jdk-8version-windows-x64.exe is the JDK installer for 64-bit systems. If you downloaded either file instead of running it directly from the web site, double-click the installer's icon. Then, follow the instructions the installer provides. When finished with the installation, you can delete the downloaded file to recover disk space.

Installers for JDK 7u6 and later install the JavaFX SDK and integrate it into the JDK installation directory.

Installers for JDK 7u2 to 7u5 install the JDK first, then start the JavaFX SDK installer, which installs JavaFX SDK in the default directory C:\Program Files\Oracle\JavaFX 2.0 SDK or C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\JavaFX 2.0 SDK on 64-bit operating systems.

If you want to install the JavaFX SDK (version 2.0.2) with JDK 7u1 or earlier, see http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/installation/jfxpub-installation.htm for more information.

**Starting to Use the JDK**

Use the Java item in the Windows Start menu to get access to essential Java information and functions, including help, API documentation, the Java Control Panel, checking for updates, and Java Mission Control.

If you are new to developing and running programs in the Java programming language, see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial for some guidance. Note especially the tutorial trails under the heading Trails Covering the Basics.

You can also download the JDK documentation from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index-jsp-138363.html page.

Comment: The OP stated that he tried "restarting, re-downloading, turning off UAC, running as an admininstrator". Do you think that an answer explaining how to download a file and how to start an executable really helps?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. It is with the help of all that I can improve my contribution to the forum. I may have misunderstood the question. But what I was trying to explain step by step. Since downloading, installing and running the jdk. I can not quite understand, but I think it is all explained in the text above. But if you prefer I can delete my answer. I do not want to mislead anyone. I apologize. Best regards.

Comment: I still face the same issue , cant run it. I cant either find installation via web. All i get from Oracle is the .exe file , appropriate for my system. Maybe should i try via CMD ?